# Telerik inline edit, window close

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Using the Telerik RadGrid control in ASP.Net, using editing "inplace" all works well and performs as expected (even got some validation) but when the edit is complete the edit/insert window doesn't close .. and I would like it to ... any ideas as to what I need to set to make it do this ?

Cheers

Comment: I think that you must ask this on telerik forum, and I think that needs many more code to find where is stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check whether you set the AllowAutomaticXXXXXX properties of the grid to false in case you perform the editing manually in code-behind, otherwise the edit/insert form will remain open. I learned that after contacting the Telerik support during one of my project's implementation.

Dick